# Rolling back action when install JDK 8 on windows 8.1

Tags: installation, windows-8.1, java-8

When I install JDK 8u45 on windows 8.1 x64 (last updated), I received a Rolling back action of the wizard and the installation finished, this is error log

```
Action 22:26:50: PublishProduct. Publishing product information
1: {64A3A4F4-B792-11D6-A78A-00B0D0180450} 
Action 22:26:50: unziptools. Extracting Installer
CustomAction unziptools returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 22:26:51: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
Action 22:26:51: Rollback. Rolling back action:
Rollback: Extracting Installer
Rollback: Publishing product information
Rollback: Publishing product features
Rollback: Registering product
Rollback: Registering user
Rollback: Writing system registry values
Rollback: Copying new files
Rollback: Creating folders
Rollback: Removing files
Rollback: Removing ODBC components
Rollback: Updating component registration
Action ended 22:26:51: INSTALL. Return value 3.
Action ended 22:26:51: ExecuteAction. Return value 3.
Action 22:26:51: SetupCompleteError. 
Action start 22:26:51: SetupCompleteError.
Action 22:26:51: SetupCompleteError. Dialog created
Action ended 22:26:54: SetupCompleteError. Return value 2.
Action ended 22:26:54: INSTALL. Return value 3.
=== Logging stopped: 15/04/2015  22:26:54 ===
MSI (c) (F8:D4) [22:26:54:995]: Product: Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 45 (64-bit) -- Installation operation failed.

MSI (c) (F8:D4) [22:26:54:997]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 45 (64-bit). Product Version: 8.0.450.14. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Oracle Corporation. Installation success or error status: 1603.
```

But I install successfully on windows 7 SP1 x64
Can somebody help me!

Comment: I have the same problem on a lenovo Y50-70 but it installed fine on a dell same OS same versions same files

Comment: The last update of jdk 8 still doesn't fix this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution, I was uninstalling some other software and it said something about the security of the temp folder so what I did was:

1. Run and Type %temp%
2. Get the properties of that folder (rclick somewhere empty and then choose properties)
3. Go to security and add EveryOne and give them full permission, remember to select replace all child objects

Enjoy

P.S. I recommend you give only the system user access rather than everyone it should be enough, but I was out of time to try it

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be originating from unziptools

```
CustomAction unziptools returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
```

This a known bug in localized W8.1 joining an AD, although it seems to be marked as fixed.

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8050838

If you are using a language other than English, a possible workaround is to go to your control panel, region settings and install the english language pack.

Also make sure to check the options as shown in the pic below:

[image]

Another possible solution is marked in the bug:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8028366

The solution is to close all open browsers and kill their process because the installe is unable to delete some files related to the jre/jdk.

The error does not show in the log because these error are mistakenly marked as info but the errors should show like this:

```
Info 1603.The file C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\jp2ssv.dll is being held in use by the following process: Name: iexplore, ID: 1860, Window Title: (not determined yet). Close that application and retry. 
Info 1603.The file C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\jp2ssv.dll is being held in use by the following process: Name: iexplore, ID: 7708, Window Title: (not determined yet). Close that application and retry. 
Info 1603.The file C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\jp2ssv.dll is being held in use by the following process: Name: iexplore, ID: 6280, Window Title: (not determined yet). Close that application and retry. 
Info 1603.The file C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\ssv.dll is being held in use by the following process: Name: iexplore, ID: 1860, Window Title: (not determined yet). Close that application and retry. 
Info 1603.The file C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\ssv.dll is being held in use by the following process: Name: iexplore, ID: 7708, Window Title: (not determined yet). Close that application and retry. 
Info 1603.The file C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\ssv.dll is being held in use by the following process: Name: iexplore, ID: 6280, Window Title: (not determined yet). Close that application and retry.
```

Comment: I am using English, and don't open browser but still have error

Comment: me too, have the same exact problem